# Woocommerce - pagination on product reviews does not work with a custom query

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a custom `single-product-reviews.php` template. On our website we use Weglot (similar to WPML) but you need to modify queries on your own to get the right reviews foreach language. If you dont the reviews are shown for the all languages for product. This is what we don't want to have.

We have modified the query to get only the reviews for selected product and current language. This works fine. Now the problem is that the pagination is not working. It displays pages for all reviews and when you switch page you get the same reviews for each page.

[image]

*The same reviews on each page and total number of pages = 45 even when I have in query only 173 reviews filtered by 10 per page = 18 pages not 45*

Code UPDATE - FIXED PAGINATION COUNT

```
<?php
/**
 * Display single product reviews (comments)
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product-reviews.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see     https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce\Templates
 * @version 4.3.0
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;


function my_plugin_paginate_comments( int $total_comments ) {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $page = get_query_var( 'cpage' );
    if ( ! $page ) {
        $page = 1;
    }
    // This is the main difference with paginate_comments_links.
    $per_page = get_option( 'comments_per_page' );
    $max_page = ceil( $total_comments / $per_page );
    $defaults = array(
        'base'         => add_query_arg( 'cpage', '%#%' ),
        'format'       => '',
        'total'        => $max_page,
        'current'      => $page,
        'type'         => 'plain',
        'add_fragment' => '#comments',
    );
    if ( $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() ) {
        $defaults['base'] = user_trailingslashit( trailingslashit( get_permalink() ) . $wp_rewrite->comments_pagination_base . '-%#%', 'commentpaged' );
    }

    $args = apply_filters(
        'woocommerce_comment_pagination_args',
        array(
            'prev_text' => is_rtl() ? '&rarr;' : '&larr;',
            'next_text' => is_rtl() ? '&larr;' : '&rarr;',
            'type'      => 'list',
        )
    );

    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );

    return paginate_links( $args );
}

global $product;
$product_id = $product->get_id();
$average_rating = $product->get_average_rating();
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$number = 10;
$offset = ( $paged - 1 ) * $number;

if ( ! comments_open() ) {
    return;
}
if(weglot_get_current_language()=='cs'){
       $args = array(
       'meta_key' => 'jazyk',
       'meta_value' => 'cz',
       'post__in' => [get_queried_object_id()],
       'posts_per_page' => 5
    );
    }
    if(weglot_get_current_language()=='sk'){
       $args = array(
       'meta_key' => 'jazyk',
       'meta_value' => 'sk',
       'post__in' => [get_queried_object_id()],
       'number' => $number,
       'offset' => $offset,
       'paged' => $paged
    );
    }
    if(weglot_get_current_language()=='hu'){
       $args = array(
       'meta_key' => 'jazyk',
       'meta_value' => 'hu',
       'post__in' => [get_queried_object_id()],
    );
    }
    if(weglot_get_current_language()=='ro'){
       $args = array(
       'meta_key' => 'jazyk',
       'meta_value' => 'ro',
       'post__in' => [get_queried_object_id()],
    );
    }
    
    // The Query
    
    //global $wp_query;
    //return $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();
    $comments_query = new WP_Comment_Query;
    $comments = $comments_query->query( $args );
    
    //count
    $args = array(
    'type' => 'review',
    'count' => true,
    'meta_key' => 'jazyk',
    'meta_value' => 'sk',
    'post__in' => [get_queried_object_id()],
    );
    
    $woocommerce_comment_pagination_args= array(
    'type' => 'review',
    'count' => true,
    'meta_key' => 'jazyk',
    'meta_value' => 'sk',
    'post__in' => [get_queried_object_id()],
    );
    $count = get_comments($args);
?>

<?php 

echo custom_woo_reviews_summary($product_id); ?>
<div id="reviews" class="woocommerce-Reviews">
    <div id="comments">
        <h2 class="woocommerce-Reviews-title">
            <?php
            //$count = $product->get_review_count($args);
            if ( $count && wc_review_ratings_enabled() ) {
                /* translators: 1: reviews count 2: product name */
                $reviews_title = sprintf( esc_html( _n( '%1$s review for %2$s', '%1$s reviews for %2$s', $count, 'woocommerce' ) ), esc_html( $count ), '<span>' . get_the_title() . '</span>' );
                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_reviews_title', $reviews_title, $count, $product ); // WPCS: XSS ok.
            } else {
                esc_html_e( 'Reviews', 'woocommerce' );
            }
            
?>
        </h2>

        <?php 
        if ( have_comments($comments) ) : ?>
            <ol class="commentlist">
                <?php wp_list_comments( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_review_list_args', array( 'callback' => 'woocommerce_comments' ) ), $comments ); ?>
            </ol>

            <?php
            $pagination = $count === 0 ? null : my_plugin_paginate_comments($count);
            if ( $pagination  ) :
            echo '<nav class="woocommerce-pagination">';
            echo $pagination;
            echo '</nav>';
        endif;
            ?>
        <?php else : ?>
            <p class="woocommerce-noreviews"><?php esc_html_e( 'There are no reviews yet.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

    <?php if ( get_option( 'woocommerce_review_rating_verification_required' ) === 'no' || wc_customer_bought_product( '', get_current_user_id(), $product->get_id() ) ) : ?>
        <div id="review_form_wrapper">
            <div id="review_form">
                <?php
                $commenter    = wp_get_current_commenter();
                $comment_form = array(
                    /* translators: %s is product title */
                    'title_reply'         => have_comments() ? esc_html__( 'Add a review', 'woocommerce' ) : sprintf( esc_html__( 'Be the first to review &ldquo;%s&rdquo;', 'woocommerce' ), get_the_title() ),
                    /* translators: %s is product title */
                    'title_reply_to'      => esc_html__( 'Leave a Reply to %s', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'title_reply_before'  => '<span id="reply-title" class="comment-reply-title">',
                    'title_reply_after'   => '</span>',
                    'comment_notes_after' => '',
                    'label_submit'        => esc_html__( 'Submit', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'logged_in_as'        => '',
                    'comment_field'       => '',
                );

                $name_email_required = (bool) get_option( 'require_name_email', 1 );
                $fields              = array(
                    'author' => array(
                        'label'    => __( 'Name', 'woocommerce' ),
                        'type'     => 'text',
                        'value'    => $commenter['comment_author'],
                        'required' => $name_email_required,
                    ),
                    'email'  => array(
                        'label'    => __( 'Email', 'woocommerce' ),
                        'type'     => 'email',
                        'value'    => $commenter['comment_author_email'],
                        'required' => $name_email_required,
                    ),
                );

                $comment_form['fields'] = array();

                foreach ( $fields as $key => $field ) {
                    $field_html  = '<p class="comment-form-' . esc_attr( $key ) . '">';
                    $field_html .= '<label for="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '">' . esc_html( $field['label'] );

                    if ( $field['required'] ) {
                        $field_html .= '&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span>';
                    }

                    $field_html .= '</label><input id="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" name="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" type="' . esc_attr( $field['type'] ) . '" value="' . esc_attr( $field['value'] ) . '" size="30" ' . ( $field['required'] ? 'required' : '' ) . ' /></p>';

                    $comment_form['fields'][ $key ] = $field_html;
                }

                $account_page_url = wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' );
                if ( $account_page_url ) {
                    /* translators: %s opening and closing link tags respectively */
                    $comment_form['must_log_in'] = '<p class="must-log-in">' . sprintf( esc_html__( 'You must be %1$slogged in%2$s to post a review.', 'woocommerce' ), '<a href="' . esc_url( $account_page_url ) . '">', '</a>' ) . '</p>';
                }

                if ( wc_review_ratings_enabled() ) {
                    $comment_form['comment_field'] = '<div class="comment-form-rating"><label for="rating">' . esc_html__( 'Your rating', 'woocommerce' ) . ( wc_review_ratings_required() ? '&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) . '</label><select name="rating" id="rating" required>
                        <option value="">' . esc_html__( 'Rate&hellip;', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>
                        <option value="5">' . esc_html__( 'Perfect', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>
                        <option value="4">' . esc_html__( 'Good', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>
                        <option value="3">' . esc_html__( 'Average', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>
                        <option value="2">' . esc_html__( 'Not that bad', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>
                        <option value="1">' . esc_html__( 'Very poor', 'woocommerce' ) . '</option>
                    </select></div>';
                }

                $comment_form['comment_field'] .= '<p class="comment-form-comment"><label for="comment">' . esc_html__( 'Your review', 'woocommerce' ) . '&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label><textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" rows="8" required></textarea></p>';

                comment_form( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_review_comment_form_args', $comment_form ) );
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    
<?php else : ?>
        <p class="woocommerce-verification-required"><?php esc_html_e( 'Only logged in customers who have purchased this product may leave a review.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

**PROBLEM**
Pagination is fixed. But comments are displayed only at page 1. On page 2,3etc...there are no comments displayed. After printing the meta data of each page I get the same data on each page.

Example `print_r` array, we get 10 same arrays with the same comment IDS on every page

```
Array
(
    [0] => WP_Comment Object
        (
            [comment_ID] => 152886
            [comment_post_ID] => 40
            [comment_author] => Edit
            [comment_author_email] => 
            [comment_author_url] => 
            [comment_author_IP] => 
            [comment_date] => 2022-07-25 21:54:59
            [comment_date_gmt] => 2022-07-25 19:54:59
            [comment_content] => Super vecička do prírody, do záhrady. Čerstvé šťavy priamo zo stromu.
            [comment_karma] => 0
            [comment_approved] => 1
            [comment_agent] => 
            [comment_type] => review
            [comment_parent] => 0
            [user_id] => 0
            [children:protected] => 
            [populated_children:protected] => 
            [post_fields:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => post_author
                    [1] => post_date
                    [2] => post_date_gmt
                    [3] => post_content
                    [4] => post_title
                    [5] => post_excerpt
                    [6] => post_status
                    [7] => comment_status
                    [8] => ping_status
                    [9] => post_name
                    [10] => to_ping
                    [11] => pinged
                    [12] => post_modified
                    [13] => post_modified_gmt
                    [14] => post_content_filtered
                    [15] => post_parent
                    [16] => guid
                    [17] => menu_order
                    [18] => post_type
                    [19] => post_mime_type
                    [20] => comment_count
                )

        )
```

Comment: Are you sure that ``'post__in' => [get_queried_object_id()],`` this is correct?
I don't think the post id is going to be the same id as the one of the reviews.
Could this help?
Did you try working with this? Look at the lower comments that use another post type as comments: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comments/

Comment: It's much easier to assign `weglot_get_current_language()` to a variable, and overwrite it to `cz` if the value was `cs`. You should also check why it has to be `cs`, which is against ISO standard. You can put that variable into args and that way define those once, instead of 4 times. Your snippet will be less than half the lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling [`paginate_comments_links`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_comments_links/) to output the pagination, however it doesn't receive the arguments you passed to the earlier comments query. It internally calls [`get_comment_pages_count`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comment_pages_count/) with no arguments.

```
// paginate_comments_links line 3118
$max_page = get_comment_pages_count();
```

As a result it ends up using the global query (see start of `get_comment_pages_count`). **If you need to continue using `paginate_comments_links`**, you have no choice but to modify the global query so it has the right meta filter applied. No argument exists for forcing the total number of pages.

An **alternative** is to not use that function, but the `paginate_links` function it uses internally. There's a small amount of logic we need to copy, but it's manageable.

This allows to calculate the max page based on the result of your count query.

I also moved calling the pagination arguments filter in here, to keep it out the template. I think the following should work.

```
function my_plugin_paginate_comments( int $total_comments, int $page ) {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    if ( ! $page ) {
        $page = 1;
    }
    // This is the main difference with paginate_comments_links.
    $per_page = get_option( 'comments_per_page' );
    $max_page = ceil( $total_comments / $per_page );
    $defaults = array(
        'base'         => add_query_arg( 'paged', '%#%' ),
        'format'       => '',
        'total'        => $max_page,
        'current'      => $page,
        'type'         => 'plain',
        'add_fragment' => '#comments',
    );
    if ( $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() ) {
        $defaults['base'] = user_trailingslashit( trailingslashit( get_permalink() ) . $wp_rewrite->comments_pagination_base . '-%#%', 'commentpaged' );
    }

    $args = apply_filters(
        'woocommerce_comment_pagination_args',
        array(
            'prev_text' => is_rtl() ? '&rarr;' : '&larr;',
            'next_text' => is_rtl() ? '&larr;' : '&rarr;',
            'type'      => 'list',
        )
    );

    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );

    return paginate_links( $args );
}
```

You can call it and assign the HTML to a template variable.

```
$pagination = $count === 0 ? null : my_plugin_paginate_comments($count);
```

Then in the template you can just output it, if it exists.

```
        if ( $pagination  ) :
            echo '<nav class="woocommerce-pagination">';
            echo $pagination;
            echo '</nav>';
        endif;
```

### Update 1

To get the right items per page, you need to pass the comments returned by your query to `wp_list_comments`, in the second argument. (The first argument is a bit long, the second is way at the end of the line)

```
<?php wp_list_comments( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_review_list_args', array( 'callback' => 'woocommerce_comments' ) ), $comments ); ?>
```

### Update 2

I had used the default WordPress query var for the page number (`cpage`), however now I see your code is using `paged`.

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
```

I also made this an argument of the function now, and passed in the value you're already reading. Does it work now?

I see it might not because the site you're linking also shows another URL structure, where the comments page number is in the URL path. Maybe you can check your URL rewrite settings whether you can make it use the default query parameter for comments?

Comment: Hey inwerpsel, thank you for your answer. So first step is to add the function in the woocommerce template in my theme. Second I will put the pagiantion variable into the existing code where my queries are located now and the third is to replace existing pagination in the HTML with the nav woocommerce pagination? Thanks

Comment: @LuboMasura Yes, I think that should work.

Comment: Argument 1 passed to my_plugin_paginate_comments()  - got this error

Comment: I have update my answer with the full code as it is now, maybe you will see where is the mistake.

Comment: My bad, I had `$comments` instead of `$count` there. Updated it now.

Comment: Now it works fine but we still have a problem. Pagination is fixed it displays the right number of pages, but when I click at page 2,3,4 etc it shows the same comments on each page.

Comment: Does the pagination show the page you clicked on?

Comment: Yes, but the comments remain the same

Comment: Updated with a possible fix for that issue. I first assumed the scope of the question was just pagination with a working query.

Comment: Now I have first 10 comments on page one and on the next pages theres nothing.

Comment: Do you have any idea how could we fix this?

Comment: Can you add some detail about that problem to your question? Check the variable values for the first page (using xDebug or `print_r`), which works, and then compare it with the value they have on subsequent pages. See any notable differences? What do the pagination links look like?

Comment: The print_r data are the same on each page as you could see here - https://weglot.artbuild.sk/produkt/fitstream-2/comment-page-2/#comments

Comment: Update question with exact situation

Comment: Your update 2 fixed the issue. Thank you